# Formulário Dinâmico

Tags: php, html

Estou tentando preencher um formulário HTML com valores aleatórios, para isso estou usando um `array` com valores pré-definidos e a função `rand()` do PHP. O problema é que o atributo `value` do `input` está mostrando o código PHP em vez de utilizar o valor em si da variável. O código é o seguinte:

```
<?php

$randomName = Array("Alice", "Thor", "Pereirinha", "Golias", "Poseidom", "Morpheu", "Titio avo");
$randomValue = rand(0,6);
    $nome=  $randomName[$randomValue];
    echo $nome;
    
    ?>  
<form name="form1" action="registrarusuarios.php" method="post">
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Dados Pessoais</legend>
        
    <!-- label: for se refere ao id do input -->
    <label for="nome">Nome:</label>
    <input type="text" name="nome" id="nome" class="texto"  value="<?php echo $nome; ?>"  /><br/>
```

Comment: Qual é a extensão do ficheiro? PHP ou HTML? a primeira parte de PHP também aparece no lado do cliente? ou só o que está no `value`?

Comment: Oi Rafael, por favor [marque uma das respostas como aceita](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/a/1079) se ela foi a mais importante para solucionar o problema. Obrigado!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Copiei o teu código e funciona na minha maquina. Verifica se a exenção do teu ficheiro está correcta e se estás a abrir o ficheiro correctamente.

Aproveito tambem para dar a minha opinião.
- Atenção às tags mal fechadas, tu não estás a fechar o *fieldset* e o *form*
- Acho que devias ter estar a ir buscar o comprimento do array para tornar "a coisa" mais escalavél.

ex.:

```
<?php

$randomName = Array("Alice", "Thor", "Pereirinha", "Golias", "Poseidom", "Morpheu", "Titio avo");

// Get array lenght
$randomName_len = count($randomName) - 1;

$randomValue = rand(0, $randomName_len);
$nome=  $randomName[$randomValue];
echo $nome;

?>  
<form name="form1" action="registrarusuarios.php" method="post">
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Dados Pessoais</legend>
        <!-- label: for se refere ao id do input -->
        <label for="nome">Nome:</label>
        <input type="text" name="nome" id="nome" class="texto"  value="<?php echo $nome; ?>"  /><br/>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

Answer (score 2):

Ta aparecendo tipo assim?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Isso apareceu aqui quando eu abro direto, sem ser com um interpretador de php, deve ser por isso.

Quando eu abro pelo xampp...

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1):

Três problemas possíveis:

1. a extensão é .html, mude-a para .php.
2. você esta acessando o arquivo via protocolo file:\\, você deve
   acessar pelo localhost+caminho para o projeto (que deve estar dentro
   do htdocs se for o XAMPP).
3. você não tem um servidor http e/ou interpretador PHP instalado, você pode como solução rápida instalar o XAMPP, WAMPP (isto são aplicações que conjugam várias tecnologias fornecendo ferramentas que facilitam a criação de sites dinâmicos , ou seja funcionalidades que alteram o site segundo a interação dos utilizadores.)